# Android. Почему, когда в любом из этих TextView большой текст, текст уходит за края экрана?

Tags: android, gui, ui, textview, android-constraintlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="100"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:minHeight="65dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hyphenationFrequency="full"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:text="hjhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"
        android:textColor="#686868"
        android:textSize="@dimen/SmallText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/itemIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/GeneralText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/itemIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:text="title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemIcon"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: потому что вы сами указали  android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"

Comment: Так мне надо, чтобы он поставил многоточие в конце, если не влезает.

Comment: тогда ваш вопрос мне непонятен. title -обрезается. а name спокойно переносится на новую строку.